# What is the simplest way to make manage.py test app.TestCase work again after replacing tests.py with tests/ directory?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have replaced `project/app/tests.py` with a `project/app/tests/` directory.  The directory contains several Python files (call them `apples.py`, `bananas.py`, etc.), each of which defines one or more classes derived from `TestCase` (call them `TestApples`, `TestBananas`, etc.).  The file `project/app/tests/__init__.py` contains

```
from apples import TestApples
from bananas import TestBananas
```

The command `manage.py test app` still works, but `manage.py test app.bananas` and `manage.py test app.tests.bananas` do not, e.g.:

```
ValueError: Test label 'app.bananas' does not refer to a test
```

`manage.py test app.tests.bananas` fails with the same error, but `manage.py test app.tests.bananas.TestBananas` is more hopeful:

```
ValueError: Test label 'store.tests.bananas.TestBananas' should be of the form app.TestCase or app.TestCase.test_method
```

The Django docs and [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) suggest that the solution is to write a custom test runner or test collector and plug it in; [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875111/running-a-specific-test-case-in-django-when-your-app-has-a-tests-directory) goes down the same route, then seems to recommend switching to django-nose.  I'd rather not unless I have to, and I'm curious to see how to make this work with Django's standard tools.  Anyone have a simple(ish) solution?

Comment: I recently asked a very similar question. I was directed to django-nose and I happily made the switch. Work required was close to none, as no change is required to the tests themselves. Do you have specific reasons not to make the switch?

Answer (score 2):

I just do [this tutorial](http://www.pioverpi.net/2010/03/10/organizing-django-tests-into-folders/).

Edit: after django 1.6, the test discovery mechanism changed. You just have to create a folder `tests` with an `__init__.py` file inside, and put your test files there.
Your test files should match `test*.py` pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be just what I'm looking for.

Comment: ick... this tutorial is gone!!

Comment: Thanks Tarsis, the reference here is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, if you run `manage.py test app.TestBananas` then you can run that specific test.

You can get everything working by making sure all your tests are imported into `__init__.py` but when you have lots of tests this becomes difficult to manage. If you want to run the tests in PyCharm then django-nose isn't an option.

To make this easier we can have the test suite automatically find all tests in the tests package. Just put this in `__init__.py` (Be sure to replace "appname"):

```
def suite():   
    return unittest.TestLoader().discover("appname.tests", pattern="*.py")
```

This still won't allow us to run specific tests. To do that you'll need to add this code at the top of `__init__.py`:

```
import pkgutil
import unittest

for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, unittest.case.TestCase):
            exec ('%s = obj' % obj.__name__)
```

Now you can run all your tests via `manage.py test app` or specific ones via `manage.py test app.TestApples`

Answer (score 0):

I use [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose)! Don't be scared of packages.

Comment: nose has been in maintenance mode since at least 2015. django-nose is in maintenance mode as well, and the sole maintainer is no longer an active user. See Jazzband.co to learn how django-nose is maintained and how you can help. New projects should consider using pytest, or unittest with the Django testing framework. Source: https://github.com/jazzband/django-nose#note-to-users

Answer (score 0):

Did you try renaming your test files to "test_foo.py", instead of "foo.py", for example?

Comment: Yup; doesn't seem to help with "manage.py test app.bananas" (or the equivalent).  Does it work for you?