# Django 1.8 - How do I test a specific file inside a tests folder?

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

This is my *directory*:

```
CMSApp/tests/test_page.py
CMSApp/tests/test_user.py
CMSApp/models.py
CMSApp/views.py
```

I want to test `test_page.py` only. I can do this:

```
python manage.py test CMSApp/tests
```

But that will test both `test_page.py` and `test_user.py`. When I try

```
python manage.py test CMSApp/tests/test_page
```

It says:

`No module named CMSApp/tests/test_page`

And when I try:

`python manage.py test CMSApp/tests/test_page.py` it says `NoneType object is not iterable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a specific test case in Django when your app has a tests directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875111/running-a-specific-test-case-in-django-when-your-app-has-a-tests-directory)

Comment: what you get when you try without the extension .py of test_page at the end?

Comment: @drabo2005 It says `No module named CMSApp/tests/test_page`.

Comment: i think the problem could be the name of the folder 'tests' because you could test by doing : python manage.py test CMSAPP.<other_folder>.test_page.tests   the last 'tests' is a built-in function which could be confuse with your folder name :tests

Comment: @drabo2005 `tests` is the recommended name of the test module. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
python manage.py test CMSApp.tests.test_page
```

You need to have `__init__.py` in `tests` directory to make it a module.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how to run only specific test(s), as [explained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests) in documentation.

> ```sh
> # Run all the tests in the animals.tests module
> $ ./manage.py test animals.tests
>
> # Run all the tests found within the 'animals' package
> $ ./manage.py test animals
>
> # Run just one test case
> $ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase
>
> # Run just one test method
> $ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak
>
> # You can also provide a path to a directory to discover tests below that directory:
>
> $ ./manage.py test animals/
>
> # You can specify a custom filename pattern match using the -p (or --pattern)
> # option, if your test files are named differently from the test*.py pattern:
>
> $ ./manage.py test --pattern="tests_*.py"
> ```

I found especially convenient the use of `--pattern` parameter, where you could just supply the unique part of test file name. For example in your situation you could just write:

```sh
python manage.py test --pattern "*test_page*"
```

This way you don't even have to look up the whole path to your test file.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py test tests.main.testMainPage.MainPageTests
```

Where tests and main are folders and need to have the **init**.py file, testMainPage is a file within main and MainPageTests is a class of this file.

tree view:

```
tests
├── __init__.py
├── main
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── testMainPage.py
```

The class MainPageTests will hold all your tests
example:

```
class MainPageTests(TestCase):
    def test_my_view(self):
    pass
```

Comment: My file structure does not have a `main` folder inside `tests`. How can I accomplish the task without the `main` folder inside `tests`?

Comment: @user2719875 yes it is possbile, you will run 
python manage.py test tests.testMainPage.MainPageTests

Comment: Does it work for you? When I do `python manage.py test tests.test_user.UserTests` it gives an error saying `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_user'`.